# Workflow error in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-workflow

I am having this error in Sharepoint Online when I run a workflow to create an Enterprise Project from a list 
The details of the error was

> Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute.
>   Details of last request: HTTP Forbidden to
>   https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/WorkflowActivities/CreateProjectFromListItem(webId='923e34ac-7127-4707-b6e1-83ac3235ef67',listId='a352ed9d-3b99-4405-b2a3-2fc3c2678335',itemId='2',eptId='09fa52b4-059b-4527-926e-99f9be96437a')
>   Correlation Id: f9d2736f-8a66-4425-a5cc-cb30adf980ff Instance Id:
>   3e7695ad-5913-4bb0-b6c8-cbf29e4e877a
>
> PJClientCallableException: GeneralSecurityAccessDenied 
>   GeneralSecurityAccessDenied

I tried changing my workflow to just send an email to check whether there is something wrong with the workflow but emailing work
I suspect it has something to do with the workflow engine service user (if there is such a thing) trying to create and Enterprise Project.

I and the admin so I have the full access but for some reason the workflow is running as a different user on my behalf.

It is a simple workflow and it looks like this

[image]

And the list looks like this with its mapping with the Project Web App Fields

[image]

Any reasons why this is happening?
How do I resolve the issue?
If its a workflow service user what is the user that I can give full access to creating Enterprise Projects

Answer (score 1):

Since this is SharePoint Online we are talking about it leverages Azure Workflows. Impersonation is discontinued in SharePoint Designer so you will have to use the `App Step`, to do that you will need to first to activate *Allow workflow to use app permissions* feature, then create `App Step` action where you will place your `create project` action.

You can find more information on how to add `App Step` as well as how to setup permissions here:

1. [App step in SharePoint Designer](http://summit7systems.com/app-step-or-impersonation-step-in-sharepoint-designer-2013/)
2. [(MSDN) Create a workflow with elevated permissions by using the SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I think this is near, I followed the full thing and I got a different error. Instead of "GeneralSecurityAccessDenied" I now get a "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource. "

Comment: @Raymund what kind of Permissions Request XML have you provided for your workflow. Have you included `<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/projectserver/projects" Right="Write" />`? You can check possible permissions for the PWA Add-in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fp142383.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 (Table 5)

Comment: Getting a different error, its now GeneralNotLicensed.  I think were getting there

Answer (score 0):

Do you have schedule template associated with your EPT?

if yes, then you have to include that template to that group's category within selected projects section.
Go to the category of that user's group, select the project template and include it into selected projects.

You can find steps and details in this blog by my colleague: http://www.epmpartners.com.au/blog/sharepoint-list-workflow-failing-when-creating-project-from-list-item/

hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Khurran, please help me with a question on sharepoint workflow schedule email - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073154/sharepoint-designer-create-workflow-to-schedule-emails-on-specific-dates-from